# How to display research findings in portfolio

Tags: user-research, ux-field, ux-designer, portfolio

I am a bit confused about how to display qualitative research findings in a UX research portfolio. I know that people spend like a minute on each project and I don't know how to quickly give them a sense of my findings without making it boring.
I know images can be the best way to represent some findings but I don't want to entirely depend on them because sometimes images don't load due to internet issues.

Comment: Checked it out and it is really helpful. My concern is with not relying on images to talk about a topic. There might be some issue with loading of images and slow internet. I want to know the best way to talk about findings in sentences.

Comment: I get it. See my answer. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm looking through CVs I don't really care about the results you got from your research - They're only of any real use to the client you were working for at that time. The *content* of your past project is largely irrelevant to what you might be doing when you work with me.

Each job (especially in agency work) is different and requires a slightly different approach so the *results* you got for testing one piece of software may not be relevant for another, similar piece of software due to market forces, UI trends, political climate, business requirements, target audiences, etc.

What I *am* interested in are your analytical thinking skills and your experience with different methodologies.

As long as you can communicate how you gathered your data, how valuable/useful it was, and how you went about drawing conclusions from it then you should be fine.

Show me that you understand what to test, show me that you understand how to test, show me that you understand the value of test results in context, and show that you know how to use the results to infer creative direction and requirements.  That's what I want to see.

Answer (score 2):

**'Executive summary'**

I'd go for an executive summary type of setup where you combine a summary of the main points of your research (improvements, conclusions, etc) with a longer text. This way the viewers of your portfolio can read all the short parts and continue reading the long parts only if they need to.

> An executive summary, or management summary, is a short document or
>   section of a document, produced for business purposes, that summarizes
>   a longer report or proposal or a group of related reports in such a
>   way that readers can rapidly become acquainted with a large body of
>   material without having to read it all.

Source: [Executive summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_summary)

**Flow**

The way you can style this is by implementing good hierarchy in your text. Make the summary stand out by having a clear title, a more prominent color, some bold parts where you want to get the viewer's attention and some space between the summary and the whole research. See the example below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this is a good idea. I got this feedback on a lot of projects to keep a quick view kind of thing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach in my portfolio. I prepared a proper distribution of the content with clear sub headlines.

- The Problem
- My Role
- Research Approach
- Findings
- Conclusion
- My Learning

I wrote it with a catchy title, ex: How we tried solving a recruiters problem through research. How card sorting revealed a bunch of problems, etc. Here is an example : http://www.imsaif.com/how-we-solved-recruiters-problem-through-research

Hope this helps.